# Why my Flagging Summary page is empty?

Tags: bug, flagging

In [my profile](https://superuser.com/users/147908/arulappan), helpful flags shows as 2(2 is in a hyperlink). If I click it takes to a page of [**Flagging Summary**](https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/147908). But the page is empty. And in the right side it says 'Your flagging history' without any content. Is it a bug or any other issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've flagged mostly comments(+1 post now).